# Программно задать звуковое устройство по умолчанию

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, аудио

Понадобилось программно переключать устройство вывода звука по умолчанию. Например, в системе установлено несколько аудиоустройств - *Динамики, Realtek HD Audio 2nd output, Realtek Digital Output, nVidia HDMI Output (Port 1), nVidia HDMI Output (Port 3), nVidia HDMI Output (Port 3)*.

Необходимо программно сделать выбранное пользователем устройство устройством по-умолчанию в системе.

Гуглил, но рабочего решения так и не нашел, кроме как для WinXP.

Пробовал использовать следующий код, найденный на просторах:

```
uses
  MMSystem;

const
  DRVM_MAPPER = $2000;
  DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET = DRVM_MAPPER+21;
  DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET = DRVM_MAPPER+22;

....

function ChangePrimarySndOutDevice(dev: cardinal): integer;
begin
  result := waveOutMessage(HWAVEOUT(WAVE_MAPPER), DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET, dev, 0);
end;
```

Видел так же, что нужно в функцию `waveOutMessage` передавать текущее и новое устройство, потому пробовал еще и такой вариант:

```
function ChangePrimarySndOutDevice2(olddev, newdev: cardinal): integer;
begin
  result := waveOutMessage(HWAVEOUT(WAVE_MAPPER),   DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET, olddev, newdev);
end;
```

К сожалению, не получилось.

Мне не нужно воспроизводить звук, просто хотелось бы устанавливать в системе (Windows 7+) устройством воспроизведения по умолчанию то, которое выбрал пользователь так, словно он сделал это через **Панель управления**, оснастка **Звук**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите тут: [Programmatically (or Command Line) change the default sound playback device in Windows 7](http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/)

Это недокументированный вариант. Но судя по развернутой дискуссии по этому поводу, такого рода задачи ms легально решать не хочет: [Programatically setting the default playback device (and recording device)](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ebd7ad6-a460-4a28-9de9-2af63fd4a13e/programatically-setting-the-default-playback-device-and-recording-device?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment).

И, похоже, это осознанное решение, т.е. политика у них такая: не трогать опции, которые задал пользователь.

Comment: Спасибо, весьма исчерпывающе!